# How to set default tab in js

Tags: javascript, tabs, set, default

```
$('.form').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function (e) {

  var $this = $(this),
      label = $this.prev('label');

      if (e.type === 'keyup') {
            if ($this.val() === '') {
          label.removeClass('active highlight');
        } else {
          label.addClass('active highlight');
        }
    } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
        if( $this.val() === '' ) {
            label.removeClass('active highlight'); 
            } else {
            label.removeClass('highlight');   
            }   
    } else if (e.type === 'focus') {

      if( $this.val() === '' ) {
            label.removeClass('highlight'); 
            } 
      else if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
            label.addClass('highlight');
            }
    }

});

$('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

  target = $(this).attr('href');

  $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();

  $(target).fadeIn(600);

});
```

here is it https://codepen.io/ehermanson/pen/KwKWEv

Comment: Your question being?

Comment: No need to use `js` just add `active` class to every tab you would like to be default in `HTML`.